Why do objects tend to flatten out around the axis of rotation?
The phenomena is shown here: https://starchild.gsfc.nasa.gov/docs/StarChild/teachers/spinning.html
I am trying to understand why this happens. I have already learned the concepts of angular momentum, centripetal force, but couldn't come up with an explanation or find one for this.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Using layman's terms here.
When a sphere is rotated about an axis, the centrifugal forces on matter at the surface of the equator are far greater than on matter at the core of the sphere or at its poles.
If the sphere is liquid or plastic and is capable of dynamically adjusting its shape, and if it has some kind of cohesive force operating to maintain the spherical shape and draw together the matter comprising the sphere (e.g. gravity in the case of planets, but there are analogous cohesive forces for other substances at other scales, like water droplets), then the effect of spinning is that the cohesive force at the surface equator is countered by centrifugal forces, and the matter in that region decompresses and moves away from the axis and away from the core.
The matter at the poles, which remains under the cohesive force but is sustaining far less centrifugal force than the surface equator, then falls in towards the core (moving with or parallel with the axis), to compensate for the loss of inward pressure from the equatorial region. Hence, you get outward movement at the equator, and then inward movement at the poles as matter from the poles backfills the low-pressure region toward the equator.

+1. It’s not even necessary for the material to be liquid or plastic; it just has to be elastic (assuming that the rotation persists), which is every material.

@Chemomechanics, I suppose "non-rigid" is maybe the word we're looking for?

Great term, encompassing elasticity, plasticity, and fluid flow—with the emphasis that everything is nonrigid.

An intuitive answer (as opposed to a nuclear answer) would be to consider a viscous sphere of matter rotated about an axis. The molecules within the matter will be accelerated outward and being cohesive will pull the upper and lower molecules toward each other so as to maintain a constant volume of matter.

The first two answers describe it well enough, but I read the starchild webpage linked by the OP.  It describes a different phenomenon, a collapsing cloud of dust on its way to forming a solar system.  Why does it always form a spinning disc?  There is a secondary linear motion of travel in a certain direction, and both of these are products of momentum:  both linear and angular momentum.
As a dust cloud in space collapses under its own gravity, the net momentum of its collapsing component atoms and molecules will rarely be zero.  The final dust cloud will be a spinning disc of particles, formed by an imbalance of angular momentum from their initial states, travelling in one direction through space due to an imbalance of linear momentum from the initial state.

If a large spheroid was liquid, and only held together by gravity, then the shape would adjust until reaching an
equilibrium, where each infinitesimal volume $dv$ of liquid had forces balanced to maintain its position and path.
If it started as a rotating sphere, not at equilibrium, consider a $dv$ on the surface, at 45 degrees up
from the equator. This $dv$ would experience the force of gravity, and a opposing pressure to keep it afloat, so
total force would equal zero. But this $dv$ has tangential momentum due to rotation, and no force to prevent it from
moving away from the center axis. So liquid flows outward.

Now consider the equilibrium spheroid, and a $dv$ on the surface anywhere between the equator and pole. The surface
is no longer perpendicular to gravity, so gravity plus the floating pressure add to a non-zero force that acts as
centripetal force, which keeps the $dv$ on its circular path.
For any internal $dv$, pressure differentials provide centripetal force.
